# Корректно ли использован падеж при отрицании

Tags: падежи, существительные

Составил предложение подобным образом:
*Такое замечание, во-первых, указывает на стремление людей даже в самых тяжёлых ситуациях не терять бодрост**ь** духа благодаря юмору, а во-вторых, подчеркивает важность духовной связи автора с его товарищами.*

Нашел статью на [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr), из нее следует, что в остальных случаях существительные <...> можно использовать в форме и родительного, и винительного падежа. Вопрос в том, подпадает ли мое предложение под "остальные случаи".

Изменить написание, увы, нельзя, остаётся лишь узнать, допустима ли такая форма.

Comment: Вы бы ссылку на статью привели.

Comment: Я не знал, допустимо ли такое. Нет проблем, вот ссылка: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr

Comment: Конечно, ничего в этом плохого не может быть! Я тогда с Вашего разрешения сделаю в вопросе гиперссылку.

Answer (score 2):

Такое замечание, во-первых, указывает на стремление людей даже в самых тяжёлых ситуациях **не терять бодрости духа** благодаря юмору...

Здесь более уместен Р.п. в соответствии с приведенным правилом: 
"Родительный падеж используется, если существительное имеет **отвлеченное значение:** не теряет времени, не испытывает желания, не скрывает радости".

А зависимое слово? Я думаю, что глагол не управляет предложным сочетанием  ***благодаря юмору***. Эта часть предложения вообще стилистически не очень корректна, лучше сказать так:

*Такое замечание, во-первых, указывает на стремление людей даже в самых тяжёлых ситуациях **не терять бодрости духа** и воспринимать происходящее с юмором...*

Comment: Абсолютно с вами согласен.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Ваша поддержка всегда очень кстати.

Answer (score 0):

1. Считаю, что винительный падеж выбран правильно.
   В Вашем предложении, думаю, "работает" вот этот случай из правила.

Когда нужен винительный падеж?
Если при глаголе кроме данного существительного должно быть **еще одно зависимое существительное** или прилагательное:
*не прочитал* (что?) *статью* (когда?) ***за вечер***;
*не обеспечили* (что?) *регион* (чем?) ***электроэнергией***;
*не терять* (что?) *бодрость духа благодаря* (чему?) ***юмору.***

2. Без "дополнительного" существительного я бы предпочла родительный падеж, основываясь на том, что **существительное имеет отвлеченное значение**:
   *не теряет времени, не испытывает желания, не скрывает радости*;
   не терять бодрости духа (жизнелюбия, оптимизма, упорства, знаний, счастья).

*...современное общество мучительно ищет гармонию духовного и материального, и в этом поиске герменевтика помогает человеку «учиться памяти, совести, знанию» (Ю. М. Лотман), [не терять здравого ума и бодрости духа](http://www.psihdocs.ru/glava-ponyatie-o-metodologii-pedagogiki-ee-urovnyah-i-prin-cip.html?page=7).*